# Vue router, show 404 page if id is not matching

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am not sure how to show 404 page if parameter not matching? For example, if user name is “joe”, and if someone open “/joe/categories”, categories component should be shown.
Now I want to add guard if someone try to open for example “/james/categories”, in this case I want to do redirection to show 404 component. I am not sure what should I fix? I got error **"Unexpected error when starting the router: Error: Missing required param 'catchAll'"**

```js
const routes = [

  {
    path: '/:userName/categories',
    name: 'Categories',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */'@/views/Categories'),
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/:userName/products',
    name: 'Products',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */'@/views/Products'),
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/:userName/settings',
    name: 'Settings',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */'@/views/Settings'),
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */'@/views/Login')
  },
  {
    path: '/registration',
    name: 'Registration',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "registration" */'@/views/Registration')
  },
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)',
    name: '404',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "404" */'@/views/404')
  }
]

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isAuthenticated = store.getters[‘users/isAuthenticated’]

  if (!isAuthenticated && to.name !== ‘Login’ && to.name !== ‘Registration’ && to.name !== ‘404’) {
    next({
      name: ‘Login’
    })
  } else if (isAuthenticated && store.getters[‘users/getUserName’] !== to.params.userName) {
    next({
      name: ‘404’
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```js
const routes = [

  {
    path: '/:userName/categories',
    name: 'Categories',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */'@/views/Categories'),
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/:userName/products',
    name: 'Products',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */'@/views/Products'),
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/:userName/settings',
    name: 'Settings',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */'@/views/Settings'),
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */'@/views/Login')
  },
  {
    path: '/registration',
    name: 'Registration',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "registration" */'@/views/Registration')
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: '404',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "404" */'@/views/404')
  }
]

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isAuthenticated = store.getters[‘users/isAuthenticated’]

  if (!isAuthenticated && to.name !== ‘Login’ && to.name !== ‘Registration’ && to.name !== ‘404’) {
    next({
      name: ‘Login’
    })
  } else if (isAuthenticated && store.getters[‘users/getUserName’] !== to.params.userName) {
    next({
      name: ‘404’
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work. There is a error: "Catch all routes ("*") must now be defined using a param with a custom regexp."

Comment: @kasp3rsky https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removed-star-or-catch-all-routes